# return table primary key name with tableGateway

Tags: zend-framework2

I'm trying to create an abstract object for my Table Objects.

Today I have lots of object like: `CategoriaTable`, `FornecedoresTable`, etc that implement `$this->tableGateway->insert()`, `$this->tableGateway->update()`, etc

I created an `TableAbstract` that contains most of those functionallities, but I stuck on one problem:

```
// In CategoriaTable my table id is named cat_id
$this->tableGateway->update($object->getArrayCopy(),array('cat_id' => $object->getId()))

// But in FornecedoresTable my table id is named for_id
$this->tableGateway->update($object->getArrayCopy(),array('for_id' => $object->getId()))
```

How can I get from tableGateway the id of an table? There is an better way to do what I want?

I guess I could inject the id name in my object but I don't thing this is a good way to do that...

Comment: I've suggested another way (by using MetadataFeature) here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23428786/zf2-tablegateway-how-to-get-primary-key/31725804#31725804

Answer (score 3):

You can create new TableGateway class parameter.(In my case I created $this->primary;)

And if it is not set use Zend\Db\Metadata\Metadata to find it straight from db structure.

```
<?php
//...
use Zend\Db\TableGateway\AbstractTableGateway;
use Zend\Db\Metadata\Metadata;

class AbstractTable extends AbstractTableGateway
{
    protected $primary;

    public function getPrimary()
    {
        if (null === $this->primary) {
            $metadata = new Metadata($this->adapter);
            $constraints = $metadata->getTable($this->getTable()->getTable())
                                    ->getConstraints();

            foreach ($constraints AS $constraint) {
                if ($constraint->isPrimaryKey()) {
                    $primaryColumns = $constraint->getColumns();
                    $this->primary = $primaryColumns;
                }
            }
        }

        return $this->primary;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Nice answer. But is this method call `$metadata->getTable($this->getTable()->getTable())->getConstraints()` supposed to be super slow?