# ZF2 TableGateway how to get Primary key

Tags: zend-framework2

I'm trying to determine primary key of table using MetadataFetature. However, the data are within protected $sharedData without any access method. How to acceess them ? Do I have create new class just to add "getPrimary" method ?

Within AbstractTableGateway child:

```
$metadata = $this->getFeatureSet()->getFeatureByClassName('Zend\Db\TableGateway\Feature\MetadataFeature');
        die(vardump($this->sharedData));
```

getting

```
Invalid magic property access in Zend\Db\TableGateway\AbstractTableGateway::__get()
```

Comment: This should be helpful [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13646338/return-table-primary-key-name-with-tablegateway](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13646338/return-table-primary-key-name-with-tablegateway)

Comment: well, I have finally created my own Feature to access that property :) However, I have already gave up Zend 2 as something completely unusefull.

Comment: @KunalDethe would have been better to write out a solution.. I'm still not quite seeing how that page helps.

Comment: I Have already deleted everything, but basically was about to create new feature, extending old one, changed the private to protected and created method to read it - getKey(), took me several hours to get it operational.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to declare a descendant of *FeatureSet*, and a descendant of *MetadataFeature*.

In your own *FeatureSet*, **override** function *canCallMagicGet*.
Here's an example of how I did it

```
public function canCallMagicGet($property)
{
    if ($property == 'metadata'){
        $result = $this->getMetadataFeature();          
        return ($result!==FALSE);
    }
    else return parent::canCallMagicGet($property);        
}
```

In my case, *getMetadataFeature* return first occurrence of MetadataFeature instance (*instanceof*) found in protected property $features inherited from the FeatureSet class.

You may also **override** this second method, *callMagicGet*.
Here's an example how:

```
public function callMagicGet($property)
{        
    if ($property == 'metadata'){
        $metadataFeature = $this->getMetadataFeature();            
        return $metadataFeature->metadata;
    }
    else
        return parent::callMagicGet($property);
}
```

Finally you can declare a *magic method* **__get** in your own *MetadataFeature*. Your *__get* may return *metadata* directly from protected property *$sharedData*.

In conclusion, once you have declared your own *FeatureSet* and *MetadataFeature* descendants, you may use them instead of current ones.
Then you may be able to call

```
$tableGatewayInstance->metadata
```

and the metadata collected by *MetadataFeature* will be available to you.

Cheers